# Laravel - Decision not to use Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-4

If i choose not to use Eloquent can i just use standard PHP queries, reason I ask is I'm using the User model and built-in Auth but need an extra Auth package for another set of users, so just wondered if this could be done or what other way to achieve what I need

Anyone have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but if you still need to use `Laravel's Auth`, your new `User` model will have to implement `Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface`, here's a glance of what you`ll have to have:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface {

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier() 
    {
        /// reuturn authIdentifier
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        /// reuturn authPassword
    }

}
```

If you are using whole a different package for authentication, you don't have to worry about the User model or even Eloquent, the package you're using will have to treat that by itself.

And at any time you might be able to use raw queries (which are not Eloquent, but Query Builder, but you can start them from Eloquent, yes).

Comment: Does that mean I could still use the Auth package seperatly to the one I'm using now and also use Eloquent and RAW sql queries if required?

Comment: Or right I see, think I get it, I'll have a play around with see what happens, thanks @Antonio